# How to find the 5th word in a line in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

How would I go about finding the 5th word in a line in Notepad++?
E.g.,

FILE1:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,col6,col7
```

The result I am expecting is the cursor must be on the word column5.

Comment: Do you really mean that the words are delimited by commas _and not spaces_?

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions you can get pretty close to what you want. To search for the text of the preceding 4 commas, leaving the cursor at the beginning of the fifth column, try this:

```
Find what: ^([^,]*,){4}

Search mode - RegEx: ON
. matches new line:  OFF
```

The only downside is that it 'selects' the text of the first four columns, but as soon as you move the cursor the selection will disappear.